# Angularjs fetching data

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm new to angularjs. I have a json.

```
{
    "first": {
        "content": {
            "admin.nv.example.com": {
                "start": "2016-02-24 06:04:12.772141"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my JSON response  i want to obtain value of property name **(start)** in this whole response but whenever i try to access this property value by first.content.admin.example.com.start

it shows error:Cannot read property 'nv' of undefined(angularjs)

Comment: var x=JSON.parse('{  "first": {    "content": {      "admin.nv.example.com": {        "start": "2016-02-24 06:04:12.772141"      }    }  }}');

x.first.content["admin.nv.example.com"].start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a different syntax to access the dotted property name. In fact it is better to avoid names like 'admin.nv.example.com' containing dots.

This should work:

first.content['admin.example.com'].start

Answer (score 1):

use `first.content['admin.nv.example.com']`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `["admin.nv.example.com"]` notation.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the proper way of writing JSON. But you should use like this:

```
test['first']['content']['admin.nv.example.com'];
```

[JSON formats](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-json--active-8817)